# Angular подписка внутри подписки

Tags: angular2, rxjs

В компоненте есть вызов сервиса, после ответа которого надо проверив внутреннее состояние или вызвать другой метод или показать модальное окно и потом вызвать этот метод. Из за этого получается подписка внутри подписки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать вторую подписку. Условный код: [пример кода на stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tvqnbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать операторы `filter` и `switchMap`.

- `filter` для проверки на значение `source` и фильтрации потока
- `switchMap` для отписки от предыдущего потока и подписки на следующий.

Должно получиться что-то подобное:

```typescript
  onExampleMethod(): void {
    this.someService.getData()
                    .pipe(
                      takeUntil(this.destroy),
                      filter(() => {
                        if (this.source === 'aa') {
                          this.create();
                          return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                      }),
                      switchMap(() => this._openDialog())
                    )
                    .subscribe((dialogData: any) => {
                      this.food = dialogData;
                      this.create();
                    });
  }
  private _openDialog(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dialog.open(DialogExampleComponent, {
      width: '250px',
    }).afterClosed();
  }
```

Но т.к у вас условие `this.source === 'aa'` никак не зависит от данных, получнных из `someService.getData`, то лучше даже не подписываться, а сразу выполнять метод `create` и завершать выполнение метода `onExampleMethod`

```typescript
  onExampleMethod() {
    if (this.source === 'aa') return this.create(); // условие никак не зависит от потока getData
    this.someService.getData()
                    .pipe(
                      takeUntil(this.destroy),
                      switchMap(() => this._openDialog())
                    )
                    .subscribe((dialogData: any) => {
                      this.food = dialogData;
                      this.create();
                    });
  }
  private _openDialog(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dialog.open(DialogExampleComponent, {
      width: '250px',
    }).afterClosed();
  }
```

Comment: Не совсем та, если случится ошибка при вызове someService.getData тогда мне this.create() не надо выполнять. Сейчас посмотрю на вариант с filter еще, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, не додумался что можно просто отфильтровать поток и не пускать его дальше если условие выполняется.